# Let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be continuous and $A=\{x\in\mathbb{R} | * \}$. If $(x_n)\in A$ and converges to $c$, show $c\in A$.

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, continuity

Note: Not a hw question. Older exam question for an Advanced Calc part 2 course I am in.

Note:* is $f(x)^2-f^2(x)=3$ (I ran out of characters) where $f(x)^2 = f\cdot f$ and $f^2(x) = f\circ f$

My first assumption is the Sequential Criterion for Continuity where if I show the sequence $(f(x_n))$ converges to $f(c)$, then we get $f$ is continuous at the point $c$ which $c\in A$.

I am not sure how to show $(f(x_n))$ converges to $f(c)$ to get this. Any nudge forward is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I’m a bit confused. Aren’t you already assuming $f$ is continuous? Why do you need to show $f(x_n) \to f(c)$?

Comment: Ask your self.... if $x_n\to c$ then what is $\lim (f(x_n)^2 -f^2(x_n)$?

Comment: @DavidGao Because you can then conclude $c\in A$ via Sequential Criterion for Continuity

Comment: @fleablood plug in 3 to get lim(3)=3

Comment: @PeakyBlaze7788 If $x_n \to c$, then we already have $f(x_n) \to f(c)$ because you’re already assuming $f$ is continuous, no? What exactly is the issue here?

Comment: "My first assumption is the Sequential Criterion for Continuity where if I show the sequence (f(xn)) converges to f(c), then we get f is continuous at the point c which c∈"  You have that backwards.  You *KNOW* that $f$ is continuous everywhere so you don't have to show *that*.  Use the converse that *BECAUSE* $f$ is continuous we know $\lim f(x_n) = f(\lim x_n) = f(c)$.  All that is left is showing $f(x)^2-f^2(x)$ is continuous; That as all $x_n \in A$ then all $f(x_n)^2-f^2(x_n) = 3$ and so $\lim f(x_n)^2-f^2(x_n)=f(c)^2-f^2(c)$ but also $\lim f(x_n)^2-f^2(x_n)=\lim 3= 3$.  And that tells ??

Comment: @fleablood My apologies for my lack of understanding. This makes a lot more sense, you are exactly right I had it backwards, hence why I was confused. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition of continuity is that if $x_n\to c$, then $f(x_n)\to f(c)$. The only requirement is that $x_n$ and $c$ are in the domain of $f$ (otherwise the statement makes no sense because $f$ isn't defined on the points).

Here $f$ is defined and continuous on $\mathbb{R}$. So irrelevant to the set $A$, we already know (by continuity) that $f(x_n)\to f(c)$. In fact by the composition, squaring, and difference of continuous functions, we also know that $f(x)^2-f^2(x)$ is a continuous function too. Hence, we know (by continuity) that $$[f(x)^2-f^2(x)](x_n)\to [f(x)^2-f^2(x)](c)$$ is also true.

Now that those facts are understood, we can address the set $A$. $A$ is specifically the points in $\mathbb{R}$ where $f(x)^2-f^2(x)=3$. We then pick a set of points in $A$ called $x_n$ which converges to a point $c$ (which may or may not be in $A$ yet). By assummption, $x_n\to c$, by continuity $f(x_n)^2-f^2(x_n) \to f(c)^2-f^2(c)$. But we already know what the sequence of $f(x_n)^2-f^2(x_n)$ is, it is the constant sequence $3,3,3,3,\ldots$. Hence, we already know what it converges to and hence we know $$f(c)^2-f^2(c)=3$$ as well. By definition this means $c$ is also in $A$, just like the points $x_n$ are.